# How to reference an earlier output in pry

Tags: ruby, pry

In python's `ipython` you can reference the output in the following way:

```
In [15]: s = "abcd"

In [16]: s
Out[16]: 'abcd'

In [17]: Out[16]
Out[17]: 'abcd'
```

What is the equivalent for ruby's `pry`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `_out_` and `_in_` variables, as described in the [docs](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Special-Locals#In_and_out).

E.g.: `_out_[16]` or `_out_[-1]` for the last result.